# Django, invalid literal for int() with base 10: 'user'

Tags: python, django

queryset (views)

```
def coin_profile(request, user, coin):

    test = Transaction.objects.filter(user = user, coin = coin)
```

I call coin_profile by clicking a link.

Urls:

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('', views.index, name = 'index'),
    path('add_transaction/', views.add_transaction, name = 'add_transaction'),
    path('<user>/<coin>', views.coin_profile, name = 'coin_profile'),
]
```

links in template:

```
{% for coin in portfolio_list %}

        <tr>
            <td> <a href="{{ user.username }}/{{ coin.coin }}">{{coin.coin}}</a> </td>
            <td> {{coin.amount}} </td>
            <td> {{coin.price}} </td>
            <td> {{coin.value}} </td>
            <td> {{coin.daily_change}}% </td>
            <td> <a href = "">Sell</a>  </td>
            <td> <a href = "">Delete</a> </td>
        </tr>

    {% endfor %}
```

model field

```
class Transaction(models.Model):    
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete = models.CASCADE)
```

Returns this error.
That means that the queryset is expecting an integer when I use *user = user*, but why? And how can I pass my user names to this query?

Comment: Well why would it expect something else than an integer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the `user` argument passed to `coin_profile` is a user `name` (or some other user attribute) you can use something like below

```
def coin_profile(request, username, coin):
    test = Transaction.objects.filter(user__username=username, coin=coin)
```

Comment: This returns the exception "Exception Value: Related Field got invalid lookup: name".

Comment: @SkillSet12345 Can you shod how you call `coin_profile()`? What exactly are you passing in?

Comment: Answer updated. Please note I have renamed `coin_profile` argument `user` to `username` to be clear what it actually is.

Answer (score 0):

The `user` that you are using to filter needs to be an instance of the `User` model.  Judging by the error I guess you are not sending the `User` instance.